# What is a cross signature?

Tags: meaning

I was told to get the cross signature done on the envelope containing my recomendation letter by the principal but I have no idea of what a cross sign is. How can it be done on the envelope?

Comment: Not your fault: that doesn't mean anything. :) You're going to have to ask whoever told you that what exactly they mean.

Answer (score 5):

A fairly common requirement, when letters of recommendation are handled by the person who is recommended, is that the recommender puts the letter in an envelope, seals the envelope, and signs his name across the place where the envelope is sealed.  The idea is that the person who is recommended cannot then open the envelope and read the letter before sending it to the intended recipient.  I would guess that "cross signature" is intended to mean this signature across the envelope's seal.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't heard the expression "cross signature," but I know that some school admissions require the recommender to sign across the back flap of the envelope, so that it's clear it hasn't been opened by you to read the letter inside.

Answer (score -1):

There may be another term for it, but I define it as a contract where both parties need to sign an agreement, but are unable to sign at the same time, one party may sign and mail it to the second party. Then send a cross-signed copy to the original party so both have a completed contract

Comment: Hello, Brian. If an answer is so obvious that it doesn't need supporting references, it is off-topic on ELU.  Here though, neither tchrist nor I have a clue what this is supposed to mean,  and my research shows that the historic meaning of 'cross signature' cannot apply here. Answers that lack supporting evidence are rarely acceptable on ELU: they come across as (and may well be) nothing more than mere opinion.

Answer (score -4):

Cross signed means a signature on photo to paper it appears upon photo and paper both where photo to be stuck on paper.
In easy words a combine signature on photo and paper

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I *think* you mean a signature which extends from a photograph on to the paper where the photo is attached, thus **crossing** the border of the photo on to the paper. It's unclear how this is relevant here, unless it's duplicating the top-voted answer. The question doesn't say anything about photographs.